Hbase 2.0.0 with Hadooop 2.6.5 : Hbase shell Unhandled Java exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:
I am running Hadoop 2.6.5 with hbase 2.0.0 .
When I try to log into hbase with $hbase shell , i get the following below
I tried Hbase 2.5.8  with hadoop 2.6.5 same issue .
I tired Hbase 1.3.1 with Hadoop, it works fine, but the issue is version 1.3.1 does not have TableReducer till hbase 2.0.0.
The issue is that it cannot find import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableReducer; which it appears hbase-mapreduce is part of hbase version 2.0 thus the all experimentation

$more hbase-sites.xml. 
<configuration>
        <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
                <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
                <value>hdfs://nn:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
                <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
                <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
                <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
                <value>/home/ubuntu/hbase-2.5.8/tmp</value>
  </property>
  <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
                <value>nn,datanode1,datanode2,datanode3</value>
  </property>
  <property>
                <name>hbase.wal.provider</name>
                <value>filesystem</value>
  </property>
  <property>
                <name>zookeeper.session.timeout</name>
                <value>120000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
                <value>2181</value>
  </property>
  <property>
                <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
                <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
          <name>hbase.master</name>
          <value>hbase-master-hostname:16000</value>
  </property>

</configuration>


> hbase-env.sh 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HBASE_REGIONSERVERS=/home/ubuntu/hbase-2.0.0/conf/regionservers
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true```


# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Optional.
export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/home/ubuntu/hbase-2.0.0/lib/ruby/*:/home/ubuntu/hbase-2.0.0/lib/*


ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-223:~$ hbase shell
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/hbase-2.0.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
HBase Shell
Use "help" to get list of supported commands.
Use "exit" to quit this interactive shell.
Version 2.0.0, r7483b111e4da77adbfc8062b3b22cbe7c2cb91c1, Sun Apr 22 20:26:55 PDT 2018
[ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class jline.Terminal, but interface was expected
    at jline.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:101)
    at jline.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:438)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeStaticDirect(JavaMethod.java:360)
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.StaticMethodInvoker.call(StaticMethodInvoker.java:40)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:318)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:131)
    at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:339)
    at ......home.ubuntu.hbase_minus_2_dot_0_dot_0.bin.hirb.invokeOther137:print_banner(/home/ubuntu/hbase-2.0.0/bin/hirb.rb:164)
    at home.ubuntu.hbase_minus_2_dot_0_dot_0.bin.hirb.RUBY$script(/home/ubuntu/hbase-2.0.0/bin/hirb.rb:164)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.jruby.ir.Compiler$1.load(Compiler.java:95)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:827)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:746)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:764)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:577)
    at org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:417)
    at org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:305)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:232)
    at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:204)

Took 0.0065 seconds
Unhandled Java exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class jline.Terminal, but interface was expected
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class jline.Terminal, but interface was expected
                     <init> at jline/console/ConsoleReader.java:228
                     <init> at jline/console/ConsoleReader.java:219
                     <init> at jline/console/ConsoleReader.java:207
               initReadline at org/jruby/ext/readline/Readline.java:105
      getHolderWithReadline at org/jruby/ext/readline/Readline.java:143
                 s_readline at org/jruby/ext/readline/Readline.java:169
                       call at org/jruby/ext/readline/Readline$INVOKER$s$s_readline.gen:-1
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:358
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:195
                processCall at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:323
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:77
           INTERPRET_METHOD at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:144
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:130
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/DynamicMethod.java:192
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:318
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:131
                processCall at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:339
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73
            INTERPRET_BLOCK at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/Interpreter.java:132
            commonYieldPath at org/jruby/runtime/MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:148
              yieldSpecific at org/jruby/runtime/IRBlockBody.java:84
              yieldSpecific at org/jruby/runtime/Block.java:134
              yieldSpecific at org/jruby/ir/runtime/IRRuntimeHelpers.java:419
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/instructions/YieldInstr.java:74
             processOtherOp at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:187
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:111
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:83
           INTERPRET_METHOD at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:179
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:165
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:348
                  callBlock at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:173
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:177
                processCall at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:332
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73
            INTERPRET_BLOCK at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/Interpreter.java:132
            commonYieldPath at org/jruby/runtime/MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:148
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/IRBlockBody.java:73
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/Block.java:124
                       call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:289
                     call19 at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:273
                       call at org/jruby/RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call19.gen:-1
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/DynamicMethod.java:196
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/DynamicMethod.java:192
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:318
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:131
                processCall at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:339
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:77
           INTERPRET_METHOD at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:144
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:130
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/DynamicMethod.java:192
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:318
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:131
                processCall at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:339
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:77
           INTERPRET_METHOD at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:144
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:130
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/DynamicMethod.java:192
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:318
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:131
                processCall at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:339
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:83
           INTERPRET_METHOD at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:179
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:165
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/DynamicMethod.java:200
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:338
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:163
                processCall at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:314
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:83
           INTERPRET_METHOD at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:179
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:165
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/DynamicMethod.java:200
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:338
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:163
                processCall at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:314
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:77
           INTERPRET_METHOD at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:144
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:130
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/DynamicMethod.java:192
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:318
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:131
                processCall at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:339
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:77
           INTERPRET_METHOD at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:144
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:130
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/DynamicMethod.java:192
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:318
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:131
                processCall at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:339
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73
            INTERPRET_BLOCK at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/Interpreter.java:132
            commonYieldPath at org/jruby/runtime/MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:148
              yieldSpecific at org/jruby/runtime/IRBlockBody.java:84
              yieldSpecific at org/jruby/runtime/Block.java:134
                       loop at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1298
                       call at org/jruby/RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$0$loop.gen:-1
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/JavaMethod.java:498
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:298
                  callBlock at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:79
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:83
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/instructions/CallBase.java:428
                processCall at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:355
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73
            INTERPRET_BLOCK at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/Interpreter.java:132
            commonYieldPath at org/jruby/runtime/MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:148
                    doYield at org/jruby/runtime/IRBlockBody.java:186
                      yield at org/jruby/runtime/BlockBody.java:116
                      yield at org/jruby/runtime/Block.java:165
                      enter at org/jruby/RubyContinuation.java:107
            rbCatch19Common at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1127
                  rbCatch19 at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1120
                       call at org/jruby/RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$rbCatch19.gen:-1
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:348
                  callBlock at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:173
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:177
                processCall at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:332
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73
           INTERPRET_METHOD at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:109
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:95
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:298
                  callBlock at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:79
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:83
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/instructions/CallBase.java:428
                processCall at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:355
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/StartupInterpreterEngine.java:73
                  interpret at org/jruby/ir/interpreter/InterpreterEngine.java:77
           INTERPRET_METHOD at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:144
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/MixedModeIRMethod.java:130
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/DynamicMethod.java:192
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:318
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:131
  invokeOther142:eval_input at home/ubuntu/hbase_minus_2_dot_0_dot_0/bin//home/ubuntu/hbase-2.0.0/bin/hirb.rb:188
             block in start at /home/ubuntu/hbase-2.0.0/bin/hirb.rb:188
                yieldDirect at org/jruby/runtime/CompiledIRBlockBody.java:156
                      yield at org/jruby/runtime/BlockBody.java:114
                      yield at org/jruby/runtime/Block.java:165
                      enter at org/jruby/RubyContinuation.java:107
            rbCatch19Common at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1127
                  rbCatch19 at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1120
                       call at org/jruby/RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$rbCatch19.gen:-1
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:348
                  callBlock at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:173
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:177
       invokeOther184:catch at home/ubuntu/hbase_minus_2_dot_0_dot_0/bin//home/ubuntu/hbase-2.0.0/bin/hirb.rb:187
                      start at /home/ubuntu/hbase-2.0.0/bin/hirb.rb:187
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/CompiledIRMethod.java:77
                       call at org/jruby/internal/runtime/methods/CompiledIRMethod.java:152
               cacheAndCall at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:318
                       call at org/jruby/runtime/callsite/CachingCallSite.java:131
       invokeOther187:start at home/ubuntu/hbase_minus_2_dot_0_dot_0/bin//home/ubuntu/hbase-2.0.0/bin/hirb.rb:193
                     <main> at /home/ubuntu/hbase-2.0.0/bin/hirb.rb:193
        invokeWithArguments at java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.java:627
                       load at org/jruby/ir/Compiler.java:95
                  runScript at org/jruby/Ruby.java:827
                runNormally at org/jruby/Ruby.java:746
                runNormally at org/jruby/Ruby.java:764
                runFromMain at org/jruby/Ruby.java:577
              doRunFromMain at org/jruby/Main.java:417
                internalRun at org/jruby/Main.java:305
                        run at org/jruby/Main.java:232
                       main at org/jruby/Main.java:204


